# Why am I getting different results by 2 Threads even that my method is synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the code I am running:

```
public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    static int x = 30;
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            getFromStash();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void getFromStash(){
        x--;
        y++;
    }
}
```

and my Test class:

```
public class MyRunnableClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MyRunnableClass aa = new MyRunnableClass();
        MyRunnableClass bb = new MyRunnableClass();

        Thread a = new Thread(aa);
        Thread b = new Thread(bb);

        a.start();
        b.start();

        System.out.println(aa.y);
        System.out.println(bb.y);

    }
}
```

Sometimes I see output:

```
30
30
```

and sometimes I see:

```
30
0
```

Why? The method I have, is synchronized?
I actually expect to see something like 15 - 15 but it is definetly not what I am getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the threads to finish.

```
a.start();
b.start();

a.join();
b.join();

System.out.println(aa.y);
System.out.println(bb.y);
```

At that point you should see predictable results.

**Added**

Now you've had a chance to play - here's my attempt at what you seem to be trying to do.

```
public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    static AtomicInteger stash = new AtomicInteger(1000);
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (getFromStash()) {
                // Sleep a little 'cause I'm on a single-core machine.
                Thread.sleep(0);
                // Count how much of the stash I got.
                y += 1;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
        }
    }

    public boolean getFromStash() {
        // It must be > 0
        int was = stash.get();
        while (was > 0) {
            // Step down one.
            if (stash.compareAndSet(was, was - 1)) {
                // We stepped it down.
                return true;
            }
            // Get again - we crossed with another thred.
            was = stash.get();
        }
        // Must be 0.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I see 30 for both of them, but I want them to share the 30. Not evenly, but in total making 30.

Comment: @KorayTugay -  Then your loop should stop when `x <= 0`. Both loops are counting to `30`. Yuo should probably make `x` `volatile` too.

Comment: I changed my loop to for(int i=0;i<x;i++) but now I am getting: 15
8 Why these values? They make 23 not 30?

Comment: @KorayTugay -Too complex to explain. Use `while(x>0)`.

Comment: I tried with while(x>0) and made x=1000, still not adding up: 612
403

Comment: @KorayTugay - Good! Now make `x` an `AtomicInteger` and work out why it now works where it didn't before.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - AtomicInteger won't solve his problem; for this algorithm to work, you need to synchronize all access to x, including the logic that says "If x>0, then call getFromStash()".  But you could make it work by changing getFromStash() so that it only makes a change if x>0 (thereby pulling that logic inside the synchronized block).

Comment: @Tim - indeed it won't - but it will be instructive. Your mods are good suggestions.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - I agree about trying to give him a learning experience, but saying "Make this change and work out why it now works" when it doesn't actually work wlil probably result in more frustration than learning. I agree that AtomicInteger can be used to create an elegant solution to the problem (and KorayTugay, I encourage you to figure out how to do it that way; hint: you have to push the test of whether to change the value of x into the AtomicInteger itself), but it requires an algorithm change and he'd have gotten more from your suggestion if that was pointed out explicitly.

Comment: @Tim - Good point. We seem to have crossed posts - I have added a working (I think) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `bb` and use only the `aa` object to create the two threads.

It's synchronized on `this` and you use two different objects (i.e. `this` values) - `aa` and `bb`. So practically you defeat the whole synchronization idea by using the two different objects.

```
    Thread a = new Thread(aa);
    Thread b = new Thread(aa);

    a.start();
    b.start();
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this.

```
public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    static int x = 30;
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            getFromStash();
        }
    }

    public void getFromStash(){
        synchronized(lock){
            x--;
            y++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I think you want to achieve.

```
class Stash {

    private int x = 30;
    private int y = 0;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public synchronized void getFromStash(){
        System.out.println("Method getFromStash called by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".");
        x--;
        y++;
    }
}

public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    private Stash st = null;
    private volatile boolean done = false;

    public MyRunnableClass(Stash st){
        this.st = st;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            this.st.getFromStash();
            try {
                double m = Math.random();
                Thread.sleep((long)((m + 1) * 100.0));
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread ---> " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished!");
        this.done = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Stash st = new Stash();

        MyRunnableClass aa = new MyRunnableClass(st);
        MyRunnableClass bb = new MyRunnableClass(st);

        Thread a = new Thread(aa);
        Thread b = new Thread(bb);
        a.setName("Thread A");
        b.setName("Thread B");
        a.start();
        b.start();

        while (true){
            System.out.println(st.getX() + " " + st.getY());
            Thread.sleep(10);
            if (aa.done && bb.done) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread finished too!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well then obviously aa will get all from stash? I want 2 objects to share.

Comment: Then share them but synchronize on another object. Let me post an idea about this.

Comment: Your `getFromStash` is logically equivalent to mine if in my version you imagine `lock` is replaced by `this`. I guess I didn't explain this very well. What I mean is that a synchronized method is equivalent to a method whose whole body is synchronized on `this`.

Comment: I will try to rework your code based on what I think you want to achieve.

Comment: What I tried is: while(x>0) and made x 1000. I also added a.join b.join and made thread sleep before printing y's. The y values do not add up to 1000.

Comment: Check the code. I posted a complete working example. Not sure if I understood your task correctly but I think I did.

Comment: I added some more print out statements. Now you should understand it. You have 3 threads here - the main one (created by the JVM), thread A, and thread B. Of course you can modify the terminating conditions as you need them.

Comment: So you have 3 threads sharing a single resource (the Stash instance). 2 threads (A and B) are modifying the stash, the main thread is just reading it and printing its current values.

Comment: @peter.petrov - He's looking to have the two threads share a pool of 30 values, so using your `for(int i=0;i<30;i++)` loop isn't what he wants (even though it's what he was trying in his first attempt).

Comment: @Tim Could be... If so, I give up :) Maybe I completely misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you print the values right after you start the threads, you're not going to "catch" the threads in the middle of the for loops. The thread scheduler is returning control to the main thread sometimes after the threads are done and sometimes before they start, but never during `run()`. You have to wait until the threads are done.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already figured out, your first attempt didn't work the way you wanted because 1) you weren't waiting for the threads to finish, so sometimes you read the values before they'd done their work, and 2) you're not looking for each thread to pull from the stash 30 times, but rather for the sum total of the pulls to be 30 (divided among the threads however it happens).

Your move to stopping each thread when x > 0 instead of after N pulls is the right approach, but the test for whether x > 0 (and therefore whether to continue) needs to be synchronized as well.  Otherwise you could test the value and find that x == 1, decide to do a pull, and then before you actually do it the other thread takes the last one.  Then you do your pull, leaving x at -1 and the sum of the two y's at 31.

To solve this, you either need to put a check for x > 0 within the synchronized getFromStash() method (so you don't actually change x and y unless it's safe to do so), or you need to expose the lock outside the Stash object from peter.petrov's answer, so that both threads can explictly synchronize on that object when they test x > 0 and then call getFromStash() if applicable.

Also, it's generally much harder to figure out thread synchronization when you're using static variables; there tend to be interactions you don't anticipate.  You're much better off creating a separate object (e.g. peter.petrov's Stash class) to help you represent the pool, and the pass a reference to it to each of your thread classes.  That way all access is via non-static references, and you'll have an easier time making sure you get the code right.